# Dynamodb.put works fine when running a lambda test configuration, but not when invoking the lambda through API gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have an API gateway, which triggers a Lambda function. The Lambda function then writes an item to DynamoDb. The API gateway can reach and trigger the Lambda function fine, as I can see CloudWatch logs after sending a POST request.

The code for the Lambda function is below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("event.body contents", event.body);
    console.log("Inserting into DynamoDb...");
    await dynamodb.put(event.body).promise();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Success'})
    };

};
```

I run a test configuration, with the following input which goes into `event`:

```
{
  "body": {
    "TableName": "TestTable",
    "Item": {
      "IngameName": "SomeName",
      "Timestamp": "Fri Oct 09 2020 12:26:12 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)",
    }
  }
}
```

After running the test configuration, the item is written into DynamoDb as expected. I can also see in CloudWatch logs, that the following has been printed for `event.body`, which were the parameters for `dynamodb.put`:

```
{
    "TableName": "TestTable",
    "Item": {
        "IngameName": "SomeName",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Oct 09 2020 12:26:12 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)",
    }
}
```

So, when running the Lambda function from a test configuration, everything works fine. However, when I invoke through API gateway, I get the following error (I shortened it a bit):

```
 "MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:",
        "* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'TableName' in params",
        "* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Item' in params"
```

This is complaining that `TableName` and `Item` are missing. However, the print for `event.body` shows exactly the same output, as when the test configuration was carried out:

```
{
    "TableName": "TestTable",
    "Item": {
        "IngameName": "SomeName",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Oct 09 2020 12:26:12 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)",
    }
}
```

Why does it complain that required keys are missing when invoking through API gateway, but works fine when running the test configuration, when the parameters for `dynamodb.put` are the same?

Comment: can you put the console log when call with test configuration and when call through api gateway?

Comment: Did the answer I provided below help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the content of `event.body` looks correct, it's a string, which is not what the `put` operation is expecting.  The `put` operation requires a map.  You could try something like this:

```
let requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
console.log(requestBody.TableName)
```

I don't know how you have your application set up, but be careful about passing the content of the request body directly to the `put` operation.  If this function is exposed publicly, that could have bad consequences.  For example, callers could decide to send the request to another table name, introduce new attributes to your table, etc.  Instead, consider parsing arguments from the request body and passing them into the `put` operation manually.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body)
    console.log("event.body contents", event.body);
    console.log("Inserting into DynamoDb...");
    await dynamodb.put(
        {
            "TableName": "TestTable",
            "Item": {
                "IngameName": requestBody.IngameName,
                "Timestamp": requestBody.Timestamp,
            }
        }
    ).promise();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Success'})
    };

};
```

Comment: +1 for the comment about security here. Don't ever allow the client to dictate the Table being written to, or the operation being performed.